# Codenameone: Set the color for the textcursor/caret

Tags: codenameone

I use a backgroundcolor for a TextField which is very simular to the color of the caret/text-cursor on my iOS device. Is there any way to change the color of the caret/text-cursor in a TextField?

I tried to set the theme constant textFieldCursorColorInt - but this made no difference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The color should be impacted by the `fgColor` but that might be problematic on some platforms such as Android. If the foreground color doesn't change that this can be a bug but I'm not sure if it's a fixable one.

Comment: Then it might be a bug. As you can see on the attached screenshot (see original posting) from my iPhone the TextCursor is a kind of blue - and the typed text is white.

Comment: I suggest you file an issue, I'm not sure if we can fix it but we'll try.

Comment: I filed an issue: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2780

Comment: As far as I can see this issue is fixed on iOS and in the simulator